# Why must I include the Telerik ORM assembly in my MVC project when I have already included the Data layer?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, telerik, telerik-open-access

I'm trying to get a simple example of Telerik ORM running on my site. I have a `DAL` which is a separate Visual Studio project.

I also have an `MVC5` application. Both projects are tied to a single solution. Pretty standard setup.

In my `DAL` project, I have a simple repository that returns an object of type `Topic` that is retrieved from the `DB`. My code looks like this:

Repository:

```
public class Repository
{
    public Topic Get(int id)
    {
        var fluentModel = new FluentModel();
        return fluentModel.Topics.Where(t => t.Id == 1).FirstOrDefault();
    }

}
```

Topic:

```
public class Topic
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Headline { get; set; }
}
```

When I call the repository in my controller:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var repository = new Repository();
    Topic x = repository.Get(1);    
    return View();
}
```

At compile, my `MVC` project is throwing an error. I need to include the `Telerik.OpenAccess` assembly to stop the error. I've already included my `Data` assembly in my `MVC` project, so I'm curious why my `MVC` project cares? I'm simply returning a `Topic`. Why does my `MVC` project need access to `Telerik.OpenAccess`? How can I avoid this. I don't want my `MVC` project to know about `Telerik`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Telerik OpenAccess ORM uses a post-build step injecting code in your model assembly providing the persistent capability, change tracking and lazy loading functionality.

This is achieved by a tool called *OpenAccessEnhancer* and in order to consume the *enhanced* project you need the *Telerik.OpenAccess* and *Telerik.OpenAccess.35.Extensions* assembly references in your MVC project (as well as in any other project consuming your model).

[Here](http://documentation.telerik.com/openaccess-orm/documentation/developers-guide/code-only-mapping/getting-started/fluent-mapping-getting-started-migrate-consume) you could find the full configuration for consuming Telerik OpenAccess ORM Fluent Model.

Regarding an example of Telerik OpenAccess ORM - I suggest you take a look at the end-to-end examples in the [OpenAccess Samples Kit](http://www.telerik.com/products/orm/features/sdk.aspx) and especially its ASP.NET MVC section. You could find the recommended approach for the UnitOfWork, Repository and Service patterns implementation in the AJAX With Data Annotations sample application.